# Cmakelists with conan

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, conan

I encounter some problems during the creation of my Cmakelists with Conan.
I just follow the official exemple but it doesn't work for me ...

this is my Cmakefiles.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(UDP_Server)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from 
https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake- 
conan/master/conan.cmake"
              "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)
conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing
            BASIC_SETUP
            BUILD missing)
add_executable(server server/server.cpp)
add_executable(client client/client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

and my error is :

```
ERROR: Failed requirement 'Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing' from 'PROJECT'
ERROR: Unable to find 'Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing' in remotes

CMake Error at conan.cmake:368 (message):
Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
conan.cmake:448 (conan_cmake_install)
CMakeLists.txt:14 (conan_cmake_run)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: That's the example from conan (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/cmake_launch.html), so you are on the right path. What's the error message?

Comment: Have you specified this on the command line?

Comment: I encounter two problems : first the conan exemple doesn't work with me the error message is : Conan install failed='1' (with the addition of set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)) and the second trouble is i don't know how add boost dependencies on this same file

Comment: Please ask one question for the conan error with the command that you launched and the full error message. Then for Boost, do the same (but first look online, there are plenty of resources for Boost in CMake once you use find_package(Boost)...

Comment: I find many examples on google but nothing to mix conan and boost .... I do not know how to arrange the Cmakelists to include both

Comment: Ask your question for conan, then ask another question for boost.

Comment: this is my full error for conan : ERROR: Failed requirement 'Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing' from 'PROJECT'
ERROR: Unable to find 'Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing' in remotes

CMake Error at conan.cmake:368 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  conan.cmake:448 (conan_cmake_install)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (conan_cmake_run)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: This should be in the question, not the comments.

Comment: `Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing` this is an example of package you may want to retrieve. HAve you tried with an existing package?

Comment: ho ok, i just editing my question. but no i don't have try with something else

Comment: I've opened an issue in the Conan docs repository (https://github.com/conan-io/docs/issues/997). This section needs to be improved with an existing package and also add the minimum working cpp file. You can try again with the suggestion I give in that issue, nevertheless I'll come back here when the docs get updated.

Answer (score 1):

The package *Hello/0.1@memsharded/testing* is only available in Memsharded's [remote](https://bintray.com/memsharded/conan-common/Hello%3Amemsharded)

Thus, you need to add the remote, before to build your project:

```
conan remote add memsharded https://api.bintray.com/conan/memsharded/conan-common
```

Otherwise, won't be able to find that package.

Another option is downloading the project and building it:

```
git clone https://github.com/memsharded/conan-hello.git
cd conan-hello
conan create . memsharded/testing
```